# Обнаружение и исключение выбросов в dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Подскажите как можно удалить выбросы в данных?

Comment: что вы попытались сделать сами и что у вас не получилось?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько способов поиска выбросов данных. Все приведённые способы будут работать, если выборка распределена нормально. Во всех примерах функция будет возвращать исходный массив, в котором выбросы заменены на NAN, статистические характеристики исходной и результирующей выборки, и номера позиций выбросов. Во всех примерах *альфа* - уровень значимости.

Самый простой метод основан на вычислении среднего значения и стандартного отклонения. После масштабирования выборки таким образом, чтобы её среднее значение стало равным нулю, а отклонение - единице, можно выбрать те элементы, которые отличаются от нуля на плюс-минус альфа. Они и будут выбросами.

```
def Maxstd(df, alpha=0.97):
    X = df
    Zero = pd.DataFrame(0, index=X.index, columns=X.columns)
    numbers = np.empty([0])
    ResArray = X.copy()
    OperatingArray = X.copy()

    while True:
        m = OperatingArray.mean()
        s = OperatingArray.std()
        XX = (OperatingArray - m) / s
        L = paired_distances(XX, Zero)
        maxindex = np.argmax(L)
        XX.ix[maxindex] = np.nan
        ss = XX.std()
        if ss.min() >= alpha:
            break;
        numbers = np.append(numbers, maxindex)
        OperatingArray.ix[maxindex] = m

    ResArray.ix[numbers] = np.nan
    Result = pd.DataFrame(columns=X.columns)
    Result = Result.append(X.mean(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(ResArray.mean(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(X.std(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(ResArray.std(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(X.min(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(ResArray.min(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(X.max(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(ResArray.max(), ignore_index=True)

    Result.index = ['Mean (before)', 'Mean (after)', 'Standard deviation (before)', 'Standard deviation (after)', 'Minimum (before)',
        'Minimum(after)', 'Maximum (before)', 'Maximum(after)']
    return ResArray, Result, numbers
```

Другой метод основан на вычислении метрики между средним по выборке и каждым вектором из выборки. В примере используется метрика Махаланобиса, но вы можете выбрать ту, которая подходит для вашей выборки.

```
def Mahalanobis(df, alpha=0.9):
    X = df
    mean = X.mean()
    L = pd.DataFrame(pairwise_distances(X, mean.reshape(1, -1), metric='mahalanobis'))
    upper_bound = L.values.max() * alpha

    numbers = L.loc[L[0] > upper_bound]
    XX = X.copy()
    XX.ix[numbers.index.values] = np.nan

    Result = pd.DataFrame(columns=X.columns)
    Result = Result.append(X.mean(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(XX.mean(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(X.std(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(XX.std(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(X.min(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(XX.min(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(X.max(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(XX.max(), ignore_index=True)

    Result.index = ['Mean (before)', 'Mean (after)', 'Standard deviation (before)', 'Standard deviation (after)', 'Minimum (before)',
        'Minimum(after)', 'Maximum (before)', 'Maximum(after)']
    return XX, Result, numbers.index.values
```

В методе Resampling Half Means (RHM) несколько раз случайным образом выбирается половина всех векторов в исходной выборке. У отобранных векторов вычисляется среднее и стандартное отклонение. Вся исходная выборка масштабируется на основе вычисленных значений среднего и стандартного отклонения. Для каждого вектора выборки вычисляется расстояние между вектором и нулём. Все вычисленные расстояния заносятся в список для дальнейшей обработки.

```
def RHM(df, alpha=0.9):
    X = df
    L = pd.DataFrame()
    Zero = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(X.shape[0]), columns=X.columns)

    for i in range(X.shape[0] * 2):
        #Random sampling
        rows = random.sample(X.index, X.shape[0] / 2)
        Xsami = X.ix[rows]

        #Calculate mean and standard deviation
        mi = Xsami.mean()
        si = Xsami.std()
        #Scale data frame
        Xi = (X - mi) / si

        #Calculate vectors length
        Li = paired_distances(Xi, Zero)
        L['X'+str(i)] = Li

    upperBound = L.values.max() * alpha
    counts = L.gt(upperBound).sum(axis=1)
    numbers = counts.loc[counts > 0]
    XX = X.copy()
    XX.ix[numbers.index.values] = np.nan

    Result = pd.DataFrame(columns=X.columns)
    Result = Result.append(X.mean(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(XX.mean(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(X.std(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(XX.std(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(X.min(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(XX.min(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(X.max(), ignore_index=True)
    Result = Result.append(XX.max(), ignore_index=True)

    Result.index = ['Mean (before)', 'Mean (after)', 'Standard deviation (before)', 'Standard deviation (after)', 'Minimum (before)',
        'Minimum(after)', 'Maximum (before)', 'Maximum(after)']
    return XX, Result, numbers.index.values
```

В случае, если речь идёт не о нормально распределённой выборке, а о данных, изменяющихся в реальном времени, задача усложняется. В этом случае можно рекомендовать использование метода опорных векторов, атрибутами в котором являлись бы вектора разности между i-м и (i+1)-м элементом, i-м и (i+2)-м и т.д. Я писал этот код для определения того, присутствует ли в выборке шум, но вы можете доработать его под вашу задачу.

```
def find_minmax(column):
    coldif1 = np.array(0)
    for i in range(0, column.size - 1):
        coldif1 = np.append(coldif1, np.absolute(column[i] - column[i + 1]))
    coldif1 = np.delete(coldif1, 0, 0)

    coldif2 = np.array(0)
    for i in range(0, column.size - 2):
        coldif2 = np.append(coldif2, np.absolute(column[i] - column[i + 2]))
    coldif2 = np.delete(coldif2, 0, 0)

    coldif3 = np.array(0)
    for i in range(0, column.size - 3):
        coldif3 = np.append(coldif3, np.absolute(column[i] - column[i + 3]))
    coldif3 = np.delete(coldif3, 0, 0)

    coldif4 = np.array(0)
    for i in range(0, column.size - 4):
        coldif4 = np.append(coldif4, np.absolute(column[i] - column[i + 4]))
    coldif4 = np.delete(coldif4, 0, 0)

    coldif5 = np.array(0)
    for i in range(0, column.size - 5):
        coldif5 = np.append(coldif5, np.absolute(column[i] - column[i + 5]))
    coldif5 = np.delete(coldif5, 0, 0)

    return [np.amax(coldif1), np.amax(coldif2), np.amax(coldif3), np.amax(coldif4), np.amax(coldif5)]

xls = pd.ExcelFile('noise_sensor.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(io=xls, sheet=0, header=0)
df = df.drop(['A', 'B'], axis=1)

X_train = np.array([np.zeros(5)])
for i in range(0, 16):
    column = df.as_matrix(columns=df.columns[i:i+1])
    #print(column)
    X_train = np.append(X_train, [find_minmax(column)], axis=0)

X_train = np.delete(X_train, 0, axis=0)
print(X_train)

Y_train = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)

test_df = pd.read_excel(io=xls, sheetname=2, header=0)
test_df = test_df.drop(['A', 'B'], axis=1)

X_test = np.array([np.zeros(5)])
for i in range(0, 16):
    column = test_df.as_matrix(columns=test_df.columns[i:i+1])
    X_test = np.append(X_test, [find_minmax(column)], axis=0)

X_test = np.delete(X_test, 0, axis=0)

print(clf.predict(X_test))
```